Creating a full, complete and an autonomous duplicate
I have an Area Light with some nodes enabled and some of these nodes have Drivers on them that are tethered to a parented object’s properties and vice versa. How can I duplicate this light an the parented object completely, and have all the data block names updated to the copied ones, so they are not tethered to the original?

When you duplicate only a child object, it is automatically parented to the same parent as the object from which it was duplicated. When you select both child and parent object and duplicate them, the new child will automatically be parented to the new parent object. Also a driver on the child object referencing the parented object will be updated as well. Have you tried this?

I've tried it and both child and parent are indeed being duplicated, but the Drivers aren't being updated and still are being driven by the original. I should mention that inside of the parent (Area Light), there's a bunch of node groups that obviously haven't been even made Single User. Most of the Drivers are on some nodes inside of these node groups. The child has a Geometry Nodes setup on it and some of the stuff there is also driven by things like Area Light size, and the copied Geometry Node setup isn't single user as well.

Well, that's a much more complex setup as the question suggested... you talk about object properties there, Geometry Nodes are mentioned nowhere. Geometry Nodes nodegroups are in a way like materials, not directly bound to the object holding them, their internal structure does not change when you put them on different objects. Only variables connected to the Group Input can be changed per object which uses the nodegroup, by default this is the base mesh coming from the input for example, or values connected to input sockets which can then be given individual values in the modifiers tab.

Yeah, this is quite the pain. For some reason I expected this functionality to exist already in Blender. Basically, what I want is to be able to copy any object and everything that may or may not be parented to it and have the option of making everything fully autonomous, every shader and geometry node made single user, every driver updated to work within these new duplicates.
